# Changing target SDK breaks view

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android Studio, I changed the targetSDKversion and compileSDKversion from 14 to 21 so I could experiment on making various updates for the latest features. But changing only these values causes one of my principal fragment views to break in a very strange way. I might mention that the code for this view was developed and debugged back on V7 and has been solid since then. As an illustration, note the following screen shots of the affected view when built for V14 and then V21. This is running on my Nexus 5 with the Lollipop OTA update:

[image: Built with V14]

[image: Built with V21]

This view has a "dynamic" layout. That is, I create the boxes, position them, and draw the connecting lines on-the-fly. But another, very similar view works just fine. Also, this same APK works correctly on KitKat (4.4) or below, so is only broken when actually run on 5.0.

What effect does changing the target/compile versions have on the runtime behavior of the app? Any ideas where to start looking to see if this is fixable?

** FIXED by making the correct call to makeMeasureSpec that for some reason was working in past versions. My bad. **

Comment: Check the support library compatibility to see if api level 21 requires a different support or app-compat set of libraries. Also, do you see the same issue when you build via Eclipse? I ask, because you have mentioned explicitly that you are using Android Studio for your IDE. Since it's a run time issue, i doubt IDE matters, but asking to gain more insight.

Comment: Turns out I was using the wrong arguments in a call to makeMeasureSpec that I was getting away with in earlier versions. As a result, in V21 it was computing a humongous height for the boxes with results as seen above.